# Cisco AnyConnect libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 error on Arch

Tags: arch-linux, cisco

Stuck with problem on running cisco anyconnect on my archlinux. It says `error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Tried to install `lib32-libgtkhtml` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935024/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0), but get error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After posting here I tried installing 'networkmanager-openconnect' and configuring the VPN in the network settings (using the same CSD script) and it worked.